# API to query Google Reader "shares" for a blog post

Tags: feed, google-reader

Is there an API (official or unofficial) that for a given blog post, lets me see how many people have shared it/starred it on Google Reader? I subscribe to a particular blog which is a bit too prolific for my reading habits, so I'd like to produce a new feed which only includes the posts which have reached a certain crowd-sourced threshold of quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official API for Google Reader, but there is some unofficial documentation based on reverse engineering [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI).

Comment: Sadly, it only seems to let you see if *you* shared it, not how many others did.

Comment: Ya.. I suspect what you're looking for may only be internally accessible. Would be really cool though. Maybe delicious has something you could use?

Answer (score 0):

Google's got a ton of client APIs that make it easy to query google reader, blogger and probably every other service they offer.  The Google Data API may have what you're looking for.  Their apis are available from http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/

Comment: That doesn't include Google Reader, sadly

Comment: It does wrap up things like authentication which you'd need in order to make the aPI calls yourself.